# Bed of Nails Test Points

Tags: probe

FCT guy thrust into the ICT world. We build our fixtures using only 100mil and 75mil sockets. What are the smallest test points I can hit with a spear probe reliably? Also using the previous sockets what is the smallest via I can use for a test point using a crown probe?

Comment: This feels a bit opinionated but given your previous question, I wouldn't chance it.  I've had reasonable luck with wedge tip P75's into holes originally designed for 2mm through-hole headers, something like the spots on a tag-connect are smaller.  But the last thing you want is a flaky manufacturing setup, you need to get that layout designer on board with the idea of designing things that work easily.  Can you get them to run the test rig for an hour?  Especially on a lot where things were cut a bit close?  Or walk into a meeting with some boards and loose pogos to share a tactile sense?

Comment: My main point, is that a team has to listen to the input of the people who are going to take on the task of making the product work in the lab and making the success rate off the line acceptable.  Just because some other outfit can do something edgy doesn't mean your organization and its factories can afford to do so.

Comment: Our company does not involve the test guys until the design is complete. We would like to influence the outcome but we aren't involved early enough in the PDP process. Is probing a 0.5mm non-filled via with a crown probe or wedge probe a poor solution?

Comment: Seems rather dodgy to me.  You'll need much more precision in your jig and fixturing than you would otherwise.  Often known as "penny wise and pound foolish".  Bring some physical artifacts into a meeting and let people handle them